# Unwanted differences while parsing XML with Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I want to parse an XML file, consisting, among others:

```
<xml>
<t>
    <name>object</name>
    <t1 name="a">A</t1>
    <t1 name="b">B</t1>
    <t2 name="c">C</t2>
</t>
...
</xml>
```

So, when I parse it with [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple):

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml");
```

I get that while `$data->{t}->{object}->{t1}->{a}->{content}` is expectedly "A", I cannot get the "C" with `$data->{t}->{object}->{t2}->{c}->{content}`, because there is only one instance of "t2".

In my script, I don't want to have any differences between those two cases - I wish to get "C" exactly in the same way I got "A".

How can that be done? I tried searching for the answer, but I only got to setting ForceArray to 1, but that didn't solve the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define in exact the forcearray, like this:

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml", forcearray=>['t2']);
```

I believe this should work. If you are afraid that there might be instances of t which have only one instance of t1 as well, change it to `['t1', 't2']`.

Comment: @Ron, One should also be specifying `t1` in there in case the XML only has one. `ForceArray => [qw( t1 t2 )]`. Basically, any element of which there can be 0 or more, or 1 or more instances.